# play sound before closing as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, fscommand

when I click the button I get out of the flash application. on which I want is when I click on the sound of his voice sounded and after completion, then exit of the flash application.

this is my code

```
Exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_4);
function fl_MouseClickHandler_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var button:button1 = new button1();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = button.play();

if (myChannel !=null)
{
    fscommand("quit");
}

}
```

What should i do whit these code

yeah i already get this
this is my code that works

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;

function fl_MouseClickHandler_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var button:button2 = new button2();
    var myChannel1:SoundChannel = button.play();

myChannel1.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete); 
}

function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event) 
{ 
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some wierd `button1` class of which you haven't provided any details, and you trying to call a `play()` method on it. Maybe you did have implemented it and this method delegates the play command to appropriate sound object but I will assume that you haven't.
Your code should look like this:

```
function fl_MouseClickHandler_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var snd:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("yourSound.mp3")); 

    var channel:SoundChannel = snd.play();
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete); 
}

function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event) 
{ 
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

I suggest you to read the following article on playing sounds if you'll encounter any other problems:
[Playing sounds. ActionScript 3.0 Developer's Guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d21.html)

Comment: i'm using that code for my button goto frame it sound and goto frame
i'm using your code too i've got error 1114

Comment: I've edited the code to fix 1114 error, try it again.

Comment: yeah thanks for the code but for var sound that your using i got an error then i change it to my vr sound code and it works thanks